# How do I prevent flexbox items from overflowing on narrow screens in my hexagon grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble centering and shrinking the flexbox items (hexagons) on narrow (mobile phone) resolutions. Flex items seem to be overflowing the flex container.

```js
function renderHexGrid() {
  let hexArray = [
    ['v', 'v', 'v', '_', '_', '_', 'v', 'v', 'v'],
    ['v', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'v'],
    ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
    ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
    ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
    ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
    ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
    ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
    ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
    ['v', 'v', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'v', 'v'],
    ['v', 'v', 'v', 'v', '_', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v']
  ]
  const hexWidth = 7
  const hexHeight = 6
  const hexGrid = document.getElementById("hex-grid")
  for (let i = 0; i < hexArray.length; i++) {
    let hexRow = document.createElement("div")
    //concerning flexbox
    hexRow.style.display = "flex"
    hexRow.style.justifyContent = "center"
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for (let j = 0; j < hexArray[i].length; j++) {
      if (hexArray[i][j] != 'v') {
        let hex = document.createElement("div")
        //concerning flexbox
        hex.style.display = "flex";
        hex.style.justifyContent = "center"
        hex.style.alignItems = "center"
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
          hex.style.transform = "translateY(-" + hexHeight / 2 + "vh)"
          hex.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        } else {
          hex.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
        }
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          hex.style.opacity = 0.5
        }
        hex.style.height = hexHeight + "vh"
        hex.style.width = hexWidth + "vh"
        hex.textContent = i + ";" + j
        hex.color = "black"
        hex.style.marginLeft = "-" + hexWidth / 8 + "vh"
        hex.style.marginRight = "-" + hexWidth / 8 + "vh"
        hex.style.clipPath = "polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%)"
        hexRow.appendChild(hex);
      }
    }
    hexGrid.appendChild(hexRow);
  }
}
renderHexGrid()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 90vh;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="hex-grid"></div>
```

I have already checked through many questions and have not yet found an answer. I want the whole hexagon grid to shrink to fit narrow screens, not overflow the side of the screen. Thank you in advance for any help <3
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz3qp.png)
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MxFM.png)

Comment: Use unit `vmin` instead of `vh`, this will keep your hexagons visible regardless of the device orientation. Try `#hex-grid { font-size: calc(1.25vmin + 4px); /* (320,8)(1280,20) */ }` to make text resize relative to the current `vmin`: between 8px at a 320px viewport minimum and 20px at a 1280px minimum. Linear equation *y=mx+b*.

Comment: Your calculations have `floor`, `ceil` `round`ing issues (tiny white spaces) depending on *even* and *uneven* hexagon sizes.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thank you for your insight, I will give vmin a try. Can you please tell me more about floor, ceil rounding issues you mentioned or lead me towards resources of this topic?

Answer (score 2):

You're using vh (View Height) when defining the widths. You should be using vw (View Width) for these. On smaller screens like phones the width changes more than the height does. Hope this helps